# Is it possible that if the universe collapses, it reaches the same state as in its beginning?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, universe, quantum-gravity, big-bang

Suppose the universe were to eventually collapse in a [Big Crunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Crunch). How closely could the universe's final moments resemble those at the beginning of the universe? Could the universe return to its original state exactly?

Comment: This is not a physics question.

Comment: This is called a [big bounce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bounce) model.

Comment: Why not? If we limit physics only to what we know now and we categorically reject absolutely everything that is not measurable (yet) then physics is a dead science... @hft

Comment: agree to disagree

Comment: In the sense that it can be answered based on established physics, the question about the final state during collapse is a physics question. Whether the collapsing universe could bounce is less clear, as it's a matter for quantum gravity.

Answer (score 4):

A collapsing universe would not return to its initial state. Whereas the initial state is very uniform, the final state would be highly inhomogeneous.

Our universe originally had density variations of order one part in $10^4$ to $10^5$ (the square root of the primordial spectral amplitude parameter $A_s$; see [cosmological parameters](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.06209)). However, variations in the density of the universe are amplified over time due to gravity. Intuitively, regions that are denser than average pull matter from their surroundings, becoming even more overdense; and conversely, regions that are less dense lose matter to their surroundings, becoming more underdense. This process is why we have galaxies and galaxy clusters today.

But the process does not magically reverse in a contracting universe. Density variations would continue to be amplified. Galaxy clusters would continue to grow until they eventually become black holes. Whereas the universe in its initial moments consists of a hot but uniform bath of radiation, the final moments of the universe would look like a bunch of gigantic black holes merging.

Comment: what about Penrose's Conformal Cyclic Model?: "In 2010, Roger Penrose advanced a general relativity-based theory which he called the "conformal cyclic cosmology”. The theory explains that the universe will expand until all matter decays and ultimately turns to light. Since nothing in the universe would have any time or distance scale associated with it, it becomes identical with the Big Bang, resulting in a type of Big Crunch which becomes the next big bang, thus perpetuating the next cycle" (from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Bounce) @Sten

Comment: @vengaq that model doesn't involve the universe collapsing. You can dilute inhomogeneity with dark energy/inflation, but that would not let the universe collapse.